# If $\frac{a^5} { a^2}$ is equal to $a^3$, then what $\frac{17a}{ a}$ would be equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a stupid question but please clear things up for me.
Would $\frac{17a}{a}$ be $16a$ or $17$ or simply $17a$?
Thanks for giving it a go!!!!

Comment: Provided $a$ is not zero, $\frac{17a}{a}=17$. See [fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}$. Hence $ \frac{17a}{a}=17\frac{a}{a} =17a^0=17$.

Comment: Thank you appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Recall that by definition we have that

$$\frac{a^5}{a^3}=\frac{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot a}{a\cdot a\cdot a}=a\cdot a=a^2$$

and

$$\frac{17\cdot a}{a}=17\cdot \frac{a}{a}=17\cdot 1 = 17$$

As an alternative recall that

$$17a=\overbrace{a+a+\ldots+a}^{17\,times}$$

therefore

$$\frac{17\cdot a}{a}=\frac{\overbrace{a+a+\ldots+a}^{17\,times}}{a}=\overbrace{\frac a a+\frac a a+\ldots+\frac a a}^{17\,times}=\overbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}^{17\,times}=17$$

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up for me!! God bless you.

Comment: @MERcurialKG That's wasn't a stupid question indeed. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Do you exist then. I thinked that you was deleted of the site MSE. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this notation would make you feel more comfortable:

$$\frac{17a}{a}=\frac{17a}{1a}$$

We typically do not write the coefficient of $1$, as it is implied, but here it is clear that the result of this division is like asking "how many single $a$'s fit into $17$ $a$'s"? The answer is $17$, provided that $a$ itself is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you sir!!!